# How to trim out extra characters from values within an Excel column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet which has a Text column Name Object Name. Now I have another script which using these columns further processing. Now before running the script with it, I want to trimmed out some characters from the object name column values.

Values in that column has carrying length of characters,but I want all of them to be 15 characters only, whichever values having the length more than 15 characters must be trimmed out. Is there any function in Excel 2010 by which I can do such activity within few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MID` function in excel to select only the first 15 characters of your cell. `MID` allows you to select a substring. The syntax is `=MID(data cell, starting character, length)`. In your case, if your text is in column A3, you would use `=MID(A3,1,15)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Let me give it a try. `+1` to you!

Comment: How to do this for the entire column?

Comment: copy and paste the formula on a complete column